# Queing files for transfer from android device to server using Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, kotlin, java-io

I have a setup of an android phone connected to a server through a socket, What I need to do is the app will contain a recycler view, each item in the recycler view will have a check-box in it once checked the file that this item represents should be uploaded to the server through a data output stream this will take some time as the files range anywhere between 12-200 MB and a scenario that probably will happen is the user clicking multiple boxes after each other and because I'm using a socket I think I can't send two files at the same time, So I want to queue the files and sort of send each file after the one before it finishes also the files must be sent no matter what the user does f the user exits the app or leaves the app in the background the upload must continue, what approach can I take to achieve this and please answer with code samples of both the queueing the upload in the phone and receiving the files on the server.

Comment: Yes i think you should queue the files and send them one after another. If the user checks another file it should be queued too. The upload should contine whatever the user does. Even if the app is exited. For the last two you can use a foreground service.

Comment: For the queuing part what dataStructure should I used a Queue and how to make sure that this Queue synchronized ?

Comment: A string array list would do i think.

Comment: Okay thanks will try using a list

Comment: You can make it yourself easyer to only start the upload once the user is done checking items in the recycle view. Only start when the recycleview goes out of sight. Then there is nothing to synchronise.

Comment: It doesn't feel like a good user experience

Comment: Also I would have to compare the old array to the new array every time the user clicks the button